# While using PublishBuildArtifacts@1 for html report download but not showing all the report showing only current one?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm using the following task for publish build artifacts:-

```
  task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: 'Extent-Reports'
    PathToPublish: './target/Extent-Reports/'
```

Please let me know what path have to use to get all the previous report with current one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the task definition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines

That's not possible for `Container`. You may use `FilePath` ... but in this case, your build agent should be in your internal network (you need self-hosted build agent).. then you may constantly add new reports to the your internal network folder.

There is more complex way:

1. Download previous report with [DownloadBuildArtifacts@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines). But you have to know the previous build ID. You can find it through rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1
2. Copy the previous report to `target/Extent-Reports/` and publish again with fresh reports.